# good open source project using Dependency Injection Framework?

Tags: .net, open-source, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

does anyone know about an open source project Implementing **Ninject Framework** or another one, I haven't work with  a DI framework before and Ninject  calls my attention because you don't need to have your configuration in XML files.

i tend to grasp a lot more when reviewing already implemented code.

also if you know about another good projects using different DI frameworks?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Kigg](http://www.codeplex.com/kigg) uses Unity for dependency injection. It's a pretty solid example of how it should be used and designed so that he can plug in another dependency injection framework easily if needed.